# Short animation (possibly part of a longer piece). Angry god destroying his creations in front of kids

Tags: story-identification

I vaguely remember watching a creepy youtube video featuring stop-motion animation. I don't remember much of the story, in fact I'm not even sure if it's part of a movie or just a short video: It had this sort of god-type character talking to a bunch of kids while he brings miniature people to life (using clay?). These people gradually form a civilisation and the god seems happy.

Then, two of the miniature people get into an argument, I think over a farm animal or something, tugging back and forth over whatever they are arguing. The god becomes really angry and destroys his creations shortly after (some of them fall through cracks on the floor).

Does anyone know the name of this animation?

Comment: Have you looked at your [YouTube history](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history)?

Comment: @Valorum: When you stare into the abyss, the abyss stares back at you...

Comment: @Valorum Yeeeeah... it's been a few years. I doubt I'd be able to find it. And ^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the "[The Mysterious Stranger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Stranger)" segment from *[The Adventures of Mark Twain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Mark_Twain_(1985_film))*

> ... Satan invites Tom Sawyer, Huck Finn, and Becky Thatcher to his company, showcasing his powers to manifest things at will. He invites them to construct small clay people, which he brings to life and places in a small kingdom. Satan expresses curiosity and eventually spite toward their creations when the clay people display infighting and inflict cruelty on one another. He causes plagues and natural disasters to destroy the small community, buries the ruins with an earthquake, and causes wild vegetation to engulf the spot where the clay people once lived, demonstrating the futility and insignificance of mankind. The scene also quotes Satan's last line from the book. In this version, Satan appears playful and friendly when he constructs the small kingdom, slowly revealing himself as cruel and hateful as he destroys it. He appears as a robed, headless figure with a mask where his head would be. As his true nature is revealed, the mask gradually changes from a pleasant appearance to a grinning skull.

Comment: It's one of those segments that frequently makes the "childhood memories that gave you nightmares" lists.

Comment: Ye gods. This is terrifying stuff.

Comment: Bingo. Man... I still find the animation freaky as hell :/ but so interesting at the same time.